# What is the best way to search through a Meteor collection using React?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I've got a collection that I'd like users to be able to search through and display the results accordingly. A while ago I was achieving this with the easy-search package, which uses blaze.

What are the most common approaches to this kind of problem with React? How do people search through their collections and display data accordingly?

I have a component for a book, which has images, author, title, etc. Each entry in the Books collection can be represented with this Book component, so what I'd like to do with this search is allow users to type in a title, or author name, or ISBN, etc, and display the matched results as one of these Book components.

Here's the collection:

```
Books = new Mongo.Collection('books');


BooksSchema = new SimpleSchema({
isbn: {
    type: String,
    label: 'ISBN'
},
title: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Title'
},
author: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Author'
},
condition: {
    type: Number,
    label: 'Condition'
},
conditionNotes: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Condition notes'
},
price: {
    type: Number,
    label: 'Price'
},
images: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Images',
    autoform: {
        afFieldInput: {
            type: 'cloudinary'
        }
    }
},
postedOn: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Posted on',
    autoValue: function() {
        return new Date();
    },
    autoform: {
        type: 'hidden'
    }
}
});
```

The Book component just renders the title, isbn, author, price etc in a presentable way. What I'm looking to do, again, is have a component that contains a search bar that can connect to this Mongo collection and query it, presenting results that match whatever the user typed in.

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the original post right now.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?